# python f-string integer with thousands comma and space padded

Tags: python, f-string

So for example two numbers `123456789`, `12345678`, I want comma thousands **and** alignment of the rightmost digit.

```
 123,456,789
  12,345,678
```

I have
`f'{val:,}'` to put the commas in place but this aligns the rows with the 1's in the first column.

I've tried `f'{val:,____}` with various combinations, values, directions in that `_____` but -- nope . I even tried nesting f-strings (doesn't work, FYI)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = 123456789
b = 12345678
print(f"{a:12,d}\n{b:12,d}")
```

The number is the width of the field.By default they are right aligned.

Comment: The `d` specifier is unnecessary.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Though it does increase the odds that you'll get an error if you pass it something incompatible/unexpected. If you pass it a `float` without passing the `d`, it works, when you might want it to fail loudly; with the `d`, if fails loudly. Depends on your desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

How about `f'{val:,}'.rjust(n)` ? This will prepend empty spaces, so that the string will have length of `n`. You just need to set the proper value of `n`. For `123456789`, `12345678` you could set `n=12` (+ 2 because of the commas). Does this help you?

Comment: This works, but you may as well just embed the width in the format string and directly generate the desired result, as long as you're formatting anyway. `f'{val:,}'.rjust(n)` is equivalent to `f'{val:>{n},}'` (if it's known to be `int` specifically, `f'{val:{n},d}'`, with or without the `d` works, as `int` right-justifies by default), but the former involves an unnecessary temporary `str`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice hint! I didn't knew about the `>{n}` thing.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know the maximum length of your number strings. Then you can right-align them:

```py
numbers = [123456789, 12345678]
num_strs = [f'{num:,d}' for num in numbers]
max_len = max(len(s) for s in num_strs)
right_aligned = [f'{s:>{max_len}}' for s in num_strs]
print('\n'.join(right_aligned))
```

Which should give you:

```
123,456,789
 12,345,678
```

If you already know the desired string width, you can also do:

```py
width = 11
f'{12345678:>{width},d}'
```

Comment: Minor note: `max([len(s) for s in num_strs])` should be either `max(len(s) for s in num_strs)` or `max(map(len, num_strs))`. The latter two avoid an unnecessary temporary `list` by generating a result at a time lazily, minimizing memory overhead.

Comment: also your format string needs to be escaped with double braces, e.g. `f'{{12345678:>{width},d}}'`

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Nope, this would result in the string `'{12345678:>11,d}'`

Comment: @MichaelDelgado: No... doubling the braces would mean you were left with a string that had the `width` pre-inserted, but had not actually formatted the `int` in question. It would only be usable for calling `.format` on it, but it would be trying to read the 12,345,678th positional argument to `.format`, and I think we can all agree passing 12 million+ positional arguments is nuts. f-strings can nest placeholders to use one placeholder (`{width}`) to provide the format spec for the outer placeholder (`str.format` allows it too, as does the `printf`-like `%` formatting, with special syntax).

Comment: oops sorry I was thinking you wanted a format string. sloppy

Answer (score 0):

```py
# generate random numbers with significantly different magnitudes
numbers = [random.randint(-1, 1) * math.ceil(random.random() * 10 ** random.randint(0, 10)) for _ in range(10)]

numbers  #  [0, -91526305, 0, 91, 7170, -448250288, 0, -36, 9521, 7830]
```

The following will calculate the number of digits quickly, handling negatives and zeros:

```
numnums = math.ceil(max(
    [math.log10(abs(n)) + (n < 0) if n != 0 else 1 for n in numbers]
))
fmt = f'{{:>{numnums + (numnums - 1) // 3},}}'
```

The output is constant width:

```py
In [34]: list(map(fmt.format, numbers))
Out[34]:
['            0',
 '  -91,526,305',
 '            0',
 '           91',
 '        7,170',
 ' -448,250,288',
 '            0',
 '          -36',
 '        9,521',
 '        7,830']
```